# Draw a decision tree with depth 2 that is consistent with the data

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

I am trying to come up with a solution to this for an exam preparation but cant come up with anything, dont know how to tackle it... if i use information gain the depth increases beyond 2.

What would be an preferred strategy for tackling this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wont give whole answer but I think if you start out thinking about it like this it might help.

Lets call the levels L0, L1, L2. When we split lets call the 0 split *left* and 1 split *right*. Lets number the rows [1,...,8].

Consider:

**L0**

All samples [1,...,8]

*Split by a_1 -->*

**L1**

Left (a_1=0): [1,2,3,4]

Right (a_1=1): [5,6,7,8]

*Split L1 Left by a_x* (where a_x is a variable that is not a_1) -->

*Split L1 Right by a_y* (where a_
y is a variable that is not a_1 or a_x) -->

**L2**

(L1 Left) Left (a_x=0): [1,4] --> [-,-]

(L1 Left) Right (a_x=1): [,] --> [,]

(L1 Right) Left (a_y=0): [,] --> [,]

(L1 Right) Right (a_y=1): [,] --> [,]

With the correct a_y and a_x there will be a perfect split.

Comment: Solid answer, like the formatting.

Comment: @user70889 thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Comment as answer. We'll this is a trivial problem in regards to n. So we can just do this by hand. Are there any combinations of two columns that perfectly segregate + and -? How about three columns?

The solution:
Let the first node be based on A1. 0 to the left, 1 to the right. Going to the left, base the depth one node be based on A4. You now have a perfect split on this side.
On the right hand side of A1, we can now split on A2. Here again we have a perfect split.

Comment: i cant see it, which ones?

Comment: I don't want to just give the answers away as that doesn't help either of us. Let's start by taking each column and comparing it to class. Which column is most similar, there is likely a math tool or definition you can use to precisely define this if that helps.

Comment: this i what i dont understand, even though i choose the attribute that maximizes the information gain whether or not it is w.r.t gini or entropy i cant figure out how to limit it to depth 2... i cant find a single pair of columns that perfectly splits the target class.. the one that is the most similar thus that will reduce the entropy the most in the following split is column a2 and column a4...

Comment: How many leaves will we have at the end if we have a depth 2 tree? Assuming each split is binary, as we would expect.

Comment: is depth one or zero indexed?

Comment: It doesn't say you need to use a pair of variables. After the first split, you can split you can use different variables for next split

Answer (score 0):

We can take the greedy approach by looking at the correlation between features and labels.

 We will count the matching of *0,1* of Features to the Label.

- *a4* has 6 matches
- *a1,a3* has 4 matches each
- *a2* has 2 matches

So,
**Level-1**, split on *a4*

**Level-2**, split on *a1* for left and *a3* for right

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tree with depth 2 that exactly matches the data:

```
1) root  
   2) a1=0
     4) a4=0 then class = -
     5) a4=1 then class = +
   3) a1=1
     6) a2=0 then class = +
     7) a2=1 then class = -
```